# Customizing/extending CGridView widget YII

Tags: php, sorting, yii, filter, cgridview

I'm pretty familiar with the CGridView filter and it's a very customizable stuff. But the life isn't perfect and I need to change the, almost completley the layout of the cgridview. (the features will be the same [filtering,sorting]).

So how should I start this "customisation", how can I extend the look of the CGridView?

FYI I need something like this [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy if you open up the class of `CGridView` you will see on line 449:

```
public function renderItems()
{
    if($this->dataProvider->getItemCount()>0 || $this->showTableOnEmpty)
    {
        echo "<table class=\"{$this->itemsCssClass}\">\n";
        $this->renderTableHeader();
        ob_start();
        $this->renderTableBody();
        $body=ob_get_clean();
        $this->renderTableFooter();
        echo $body; // TFOOT must appear before TBODY according to the standard.
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else
        $this->renderEmptyText();
}
```

you basically need to extend the class, put it in a folder that you can access it in extensions, and override methods in this function

Comment: I looked the code and it's pretty undestandable. The only problem is that I need to put specific data to specific places and i think this CGridView idea is pretty bad for this problem.

Comment: I think extending is better than writing all over again, try to render the parts like your markup, or have more fields that you can assign values to.

Comment: I just discovered the CListView and it's perfect for what I need. It's pretty easy to use filters with it.

Anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To change the grid appearence do not change the mother file(`CGridView.php in yii\framework\zii\widgets\grid`). Extend the CGridView to new Class and change the HTML structure.

[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/528/insert-a-multirow-header-in-cgridview/) is the good explonation.